# jQuery jFeed plugin working with the domain with www and without it

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, jfeed

I use jQuery jFeed plugin to fetch rss feed from WordPress blog and show on the main page of the site. So, it works fine when I go to **http://site-using-jfeed.com**. But when go to **http://www.site-using-jfeed.com**, it doesn't load the feed and nothing is shown. I suppose there is something about cross-domain functionality. What can I do about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), and you won't be able to get data from other servers unless you fetch it on the back-end or use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP).